# part of Regex match

Tags: regex, match

I'm trying to upgrade my regex skills. How do I made a regex which for this text return these 3 matches

---

496 VF : Vapeurs Enivrantes

497 VF : Le Cadeau du Kazekage

498 VF : La dernière mission

---

1. 496 Vapeurs Enivrantes
2. 497 Le Cadeau du Kazekage
3. 498 La dernière mission

---

I don't want to use any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

So, you think about digits (or space?) from begin and text after `:`:

```
^([0-9]+)[^:]+ (.+)$
^([^ ]+)[^:]+ (.+)$ <-- or use space as delimiter
```

and you have begin and end of text in `\1` `\2` or `$1` `$2` by language.

Comment: ok i was thinking something like that(?<= VF : )(.*)(?=\n|) because yours dont seem to works

Comment: But in fact i was hopping that regex can match a pattern separated by a string here "VF : ". Because here we must use \1 and \2 and I was hopping that was uncessary with a good regex.